# Compiling Linux and Creating Bootable ISO Image

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bootable

I have already compiled Linux kernel 3.12.6 but did not install it into `/boot` as I did not want my hard disk to have another OS.

I have the compiled `bzImage` and I don't know how to take that and create a bootable ISO. When I created my own OS, I used `grub-mkrescue -o` to create a grub-bootable ISO, however, Linux is **way** more complicated, so I am not sure how to do it.

My objective is to test the `.iso` in an emulator (`qemu`) and not on actual CD/DVD (at least not for now)

Comment: A Linux kernel is not an OS. If you only have that, you won't be able to do anything with it except boot until it fails to mount `/`. What are you trying to do exactly.

Comment: For now that is OK for me. I know Linux is just a kernel NOT an OS, as there are no GNU utilities (to make it GNU/Linux). However, for my initial purposes I am fine with just the kernel.

Comment: Ok, so what's not working when you try with `grub-mkrescue` or isolinux?

Comment: I don't know what files should be in the directory to provide `grub-mkrescue`. I know a grub.cfg file is needed with info on where the Linux is. But what else is needed and where to put those files

Comment: Your kernel image and that's about it.